# How to plot chart with duplicate date values?

Tags: date, tableau-api

I am new to the tableau public platform, i would like to know how i can plot a chart which will show multiple duplicate date values on the x-axis.

any guide would be very much appreciated.  Thank you

sample data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to turn off Aggregate Measures, see the Analysis menu.

If you have a dimension that uniquely identifies rows, say transaction Id, then you can put that on the detail shelf, and convert the date field to an a measure or attribute.